# Hg: copy file without saving history (copy as new file)

Tags: mercurial, pycharm, tortoisehg

I am making copy of existing files in a folder (selecting them in Pycharm, copying and pasting to another folder).

Also I tried to make a copy of files in Mac OS terminal

```
cp -R source_folder destination_folder
```

In both cases TortoiseHG show that the file has been copied from its source. How to make a copy of files without saving the history? I need the file to be created as a new one

It's possible if I manually create a new file and copying the content of source file to the new one. But it's much more complex way if you have plenty of files to copy

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found the solution. I guess that copying from Pycharm executes `hg copy` command (that was mentioned in other questions).

Copying from terminal is ok, but I forgot to `forget` previously copied files. I clicked with right button on filename in TortoiseHG and chosen forget option. Then copied from terminal window as I made before

```
cp -R source_folder destination_folder
```

And thats it